# BI publisher portrait landascape in the same document

Tags: rtf, landscape-portrait, bi-publisher

I'm quite new in the BI publisher as well on Stackoverflow but here there are always guys with great solution.
I'm using BI publisher on Word to create an RTF which pulls data from an XML.

I need to produce a first part of the document with portrait layout then there is a table with many columns and I'd like to put that table in landascape layout .

I did maybe the easiest and silliest thing I could do. I created a page break section before the table and from that point on I set orientation landscape.
But when I run the report I always have this error org.xml.sax.SAXException: element xdofo:start is not supported yet.

Thanks to everybody could help me

Here the detail of the error I get:

```
oracle.xdo.XDOSAXException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: element xdofo:start is not supported yet.
at oracle.xdo.template.fo.FOProcessingEngine.process(FOProcessingEngine.java:463)
at oracle.xdo.template.FOProcessor.generate(FOProcessor.java:1291)
at RTF2PDF2.runRTFto(RTF2PDF2.java:484)
at RTF2PDF2.runXDO(RTF2PDF2.java:343)
at RTF2PDF2.main(RTF2PDF2.java:235)
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: element xdofo:start is not supported yet.
at oracle.xdo.template.fo.FOHandler.startElement(FOHandler.java:315)
at oracle.xdo.common.xml.XSLTHandler$SEEntry.sendEvent(XSLTHandler.java:542)
at oracle.xdo.common.xml.XSLTMerger.startElement(XSLTMerger.java:51)
at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.XMLContentHandler.startElement(XMLContentHandler.java:182)
at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1322)
at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:366)
at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:312)
at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:218)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at oracle.xdo.common.xml.XDOSAXParser.invokeParse(XDOSAXParser.java:300)
at oracle.xdo.common.xml.XDOSAXParser.parse(XDOSAXParser.java:149)
at oracle.xdo.template.fo.FOProcessingEngine.process(FOProcessingEngine.java:449)
```

Comment: Is your report multiple rows will have both portrait and landscape? Or is your report a single record which will have a portrait section, and a landscape section? I did a test with desktop version; if its just 1 record spread across a P and L, it works. If there's a for-each which spans a P and L, it does strange things. But it doesn't fail on me.

Comment: Thank you EdHayes3 for your reply. 
The report is quite complex so in the portrait section there are cycles,tables with multiple rows,complex condition(if then else). 
The portrait section contains the data of a client, multiple addresses, connection data with other clients and so on.
The landscape section contains a table with all the vehicles owned by the business and I need to put that table on the landscape. Multiple rows pulled from the xml with a for each cycle. But the data are different I'm not trying to spread a part of the structure portrait and the other on the landscape.

Comment: Will this report be run for multiple clients at once where it will go ClientA-Portrait, CliantA-Landscape, ClientB-Portrait, ClientB-Landscape...?

Comment: Hi EdHayes3, the report is ClientA Portrait , Cliant A Landscape  not multiple clients at one

Comment: Then I don't think you should have any problem. Did you test it out with the BI Publisher desktop template viewer?

Comment: If you can post your template you are testing somewhere, and share it here, I could take a look at it.